# Riak, is there an advantage to shortening bucket name?

Tags: riak

I plan to store a whole lot bunch of data in a Riak bucket. As the documentation shows, the bucket name is stored in the object itself.

See:

http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/planning/cluster/
http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/planning/bitcask/

Should I make my bucket and bucket types name 2 character long and cryptic to save resources ?

Comment: I think the question you should ask yourself first is whether your code will be easy to maintain and troubleshoot with cryptic bucket names or not. I don't know if the performance gain from using short names will be significant.

Comment: Your savings will depend on your object size and number of objects.  For each character you shave off of the bucket name, you will save 1 byte on disk.  So if you use a 2 character bucket instead of 30, and you are storing 32kb objects, you will reduce your storage requirement by 0.085%, but if your objects are 1k, your space savings is 2.7%.  Whether that is worthwhile will depend on how many objects you store, but even if you actually store a billion objects, your space savings in this example would be less than what you can store on your phone.

Comment: It's not only about storage, but also about a communication overhead. Same goes for keys, BTW. Still, I think the impact will be negligible, especially compared to the benefit of having clear, descriptive names.